# Stack navigater not working react native

Tags: reactjs

When using stacknavigater, it is showing error

> " undefined is not an
>   object(evaluating'_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

1-import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
when add onPress event it shows error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import anything.
Jist define routes by createStackNavigator.

```
export default createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
});
```

React Navigation provides API via props.
You need to use the props to transite.

Use Navigation props.
this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")
is example.

```
render() {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
  return (
    <Button title="press" onPress ={() => navigate("Home")}/>
```

I recomend to confirm your props by consolr.log(this.props)

Define your routes by stackNavigator.

read this "Moving between screens"
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html

Comment: it shows the same error undefined is not an obhect(evaluating ' this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: 1. I think you forgot to export default.
2. React Navigation don't use this.props.navigation in child component.
to solve this pass props to child component like
<ChildButton navigation={this.props.navigation.navigate} route={"Home"}>
in ChildButton
onPress={() => this.props.navigation(this.props.route)}

Comment: acutally i am createing a small aplication in which first a splash screen came then an activity came with a  start button  so want to add navigation to go other screen to this start button

Comment: then check stackNavigator.
undefined is not an object(evaluating'_this2.props.navigation.navigate')
says that props.navigation is undefiend.
So you need pass porps to your component.
const AccountSubNav = StackNavigator(
  {
    LandingScreen: {screen: LandingScreen},
})
is example